# How to align the divs in my case?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to setup a div inside another div. My question is how do I set the red child div to be vertical align to middle and have smaller height than the parent div. See my codes.

html

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="sub-wrapper">   //Need this div to be vertical align to middle  
          text here              //and smaller height         
     </div>
     <div class="bottom-wrapper">
         another text       
     </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

.sub-wrapper {
    display: table-cell; //I use table-cell to vertical align to middle
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px; //set 20px but doesn't take effect...
}


.bottom-wrapper {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 40%;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zccdcmp5/1/

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**Vertical alignment**

You need to add `vertical-align: middle` CSS property in order to place your text in the middle vertically. Just add this to the `.sub-wrapper` declaration:

```
.sub-wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;

    vertical-align: middle; // Here it is :)
}
```

Here is [an updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zccdcmp5/2/).

**Height**

You cannot make the height of the only `div` be less than its parent's (table's) height as long as it is rendered as a table cell. Cells fill the table.

There are several ways to do this. You can use `padding`, `margin` or create a container with margin. However, why do you want to do it?

Comment: Thanks. I also need the sub-wrapper div to be 20px and vertical align to middle too. +1

Comment: @FlyingCat Why do you want this? :) I have updated the answer.

Comment: TY @Yeldar. The red div is still filling the whole parent div. :(

Answer (score 0):

The css trick for vertical centering (you may have any height for your parent or child):

1. `position: relative` for the parent
2. `position: absolute` on the child
3. `top: 50%` on the child
4. `-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%)` on the child, add other vendors in real use

Be sure to remove `display: table` (or table-cell) when trying this.

This will center align the child, and because of the absolute position, other siblings will not align below this centered child. The table-cell will force you to eventually take up the whole space, you can add another wrapping to have custom height. My solution here may be less verbose if different heights matters.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this it will make `vertical-align:middle` and makes text to the center..

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align:center;
}

.sub-wrapper {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
}


.bottom-wrapper {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 40%;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` will give you, your required output.

Check following:

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-wrapper {
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: calc(60% - 2px);
}
.bottom-wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="sub-wrapper">
            text here
        </div><div class="bottom-wrapper">
        </div>
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zccdcmp5/7/)

Hope it helps.